# Deserialization of map with integer keys using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, fasterxml

I have to serialize a simple integer-to-string map as JSON and then read it back. 
The serialization is pretty simple, however since JSON keys must be strings the resulting JSON looks like:

```
{
  "123" : "hello",
  "456" : "bye",
}
```

When I read it using code like:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class)
```

I get `Map<String, String>` instead of `Map<Integer, String>` that I need.

I tried to add key deserializer as following:

```
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, "foo");
    map1.put(2, "bar");


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addKeyDeserializer(Integer.class, new KeyDeserializer() {
        @Override
        public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            System.out.println("deserialize " + key);
            return Integer.parseInt(key);
        }
    });

    mapper.registerModule(module);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map1);


    Map map2 = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
    System.out.println(map2);
    System.out.println(map2.keySet().iterator().next().getClass());
```

Unfortunately my key deserialzier is never called and `map2` is in fact `Map<String, String>`, so my example prints:

```
{1=foo, 2=bar}
class java.lang.String
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix the problem?

Comment: lol I've got the same issue. Quite surprising you don't have more upvotes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
Map<Integer, String> map2 = 
        mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<Integer, String>>(){});
```

or

```
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = 
        mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                         .constructMapType(HashMap.class, Integer.class, String.class));
```

Your program will output below text:

```
deserialize 1
deserialize 2
{1=foo, 2=bar}
class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. This is surely the best solution for me. However it is still interesting why my solution does not work.

Comment: Jackson did not know the types of key and values of your Map. It need to be told about that.  If you were de-serializing to a POJO, and that POJO had a Map<Integer, String>, then, Jackson seems to know what to do.  However, when parsing Map directly, the above seems to be the way to inform Jackson about it

Comment: I see. Now it is clear. Thanks a lot for the explanations.

Comment: Even if I use `map1` in left hand side of `mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);` then why it does not complain? The key of map1 is `Integer` but when I use `getClass()` it is printed as `String`. What happens here during deserialiazation?