# When deserializing a map with Long keys from JSON using an jackson objectmapper, the Long keys are being deserialized as Strings

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, objectmapper

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class ObjectMapperTest {

    @Test
    fun hello() {
        val objectMapper = objectMapper()

        val map: Map<Long, String> = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapOf(1L to "hi", 2L to "hello")), Map::class.java) as Map<Long, String>
        assertThat(map[1L]).isEqualTo("hi")
    }

    private fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(KotlinModule())
            .activateDefaultTyping(
                BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().allowIfBaseType(Any::class.java).build(),
                ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING
            )

        return objectMapper
    }

}
```

As i already found that json key must be String type from [this post](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/347) , but i want to make this test code to be passed. Is there any Jackson ObjectMapper configurations to apply? I already tried some options or make custom KeyDeserializer but failed. How can i fix it?

Exactly, i want to use object mapper as a serializer/deserializer for redis cache. So it impelements RedisSerializer and i have to use Generic and Type Reference. So using jacksonTypeRef() doesn't work!

```
override fun deserialize(bytes: ByteArray?): T? {
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null
    }

    if (!isGzipCompressed(bytes)) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, jacksonTypeRef()) // Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
        // return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, object : TypeReference<T>() {}) doesn't work
    }

    try {
        val byteArrayHolder = decodeGzip(bytes)
        return objectMapper.readValue(byteArrayHolder.rawByteArray, 0, byteArrayHolder.limit, object : TypeReference<T>() {})
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        throw IllegalStateException("couldn't encode body to gzip", ex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialization of map with integer keys using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230918/deserialization-of-map-with-integer-keys-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the map key type using a type reference.

The duplicate question I suggested is for Java. Kotlin has slightly different syntax, which looks like:

```
val map: Map<Long, String> = objectMapper.readValue(
    """{"1":"a","2":b"}""",
    jacksonTypeRef(),
)
```

or

```
val map = objectMapper.readValue(
    """{"1":"a","2":b"}""",
    jacksonTypeRef<Map<Long, String>>(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works but it cannot solve my real problem. can you help again?
I updated my question!

Comment: This appears to be a limitation of the Spring Data Redis `RedisSerializer` interface. If you know all maps stored in the cache have numeric keys, perhaps you could transform the resulting map inside the deserializer. Our you could lobby for an improvement to Spring Data Redis, along the lines of: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/2374

Comment: Or maybe  a [`Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.html) constructed with an appropriate JavaType would do what you want?

Comment: To create a `JavaType` from a `TypeReference`, call `objectMapper.constructType(myTypeReference)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! But Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer does not support gzip compression. I tried many things to solve the problem by referring to your answer, but it didn't work.